# Trigger and monitor Content Migrator preset from SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions, content-migration, sitecore-sidekick

Does anyone know if there is a way of triggering Sitecore Sidekicks's Content Migrator from within Sitecore using SPE and monitor progress? Sidekick's Content Migrator scripting works for Powershell instances outside of Sitecore, which I could use with SPE remoting, but there is no way to monitor the progress of the migration. I'd like to be able to trigger a pre-defined content pull followed by an index rebuild, links database rebuild and a couple of custom scripts for shuffling some renderings around and finally a site republish.

The reason for Content Migrator, and not some other form of content pull, is that there are about 150k items and Item Blaster seems to be the fastest way of getting them from one environment to the other.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/michaellwest/Spe-Content-Migrator

Comment: @MichaelWest I haven't, yet, but I will now. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexTselevich you can also try to use https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool.aspx Win app tool if you need the fastest migration, it works with DBs and does not require a Sitecore instance. You can skip files migration and can pick master or core DBs to migrate the content. But don't forget to re-index items etc. after migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael West's answer of using SPE Content Migrator in conjunction with SPE Remoting, instead of Sidekick's Content Migrator, worked a charm.